# Are big city residents healthier due to walking? (all else roughly equal)

Tags: exercise, lifestyle, benefits, environmental-conditions, walking

Is there any study that explores whether people in big cities physically exert themselves more as part of their daily routine to the benefit of their physical health?

My thinking is this: people living in big cities (e.g. London, New York) often do not own a car and rely on public transport to commute to work 5 days a week. This might involve walking from their home to a subway station (and maybe climbing some stairs) as well as walking several blocks to their office when alighting from the subway. This is physically strenuous and something that those taking a car do not have to endure (I speak from experience, going to college in London but now being spoilt by the suburban California lifestyle).

In practice I know that there are many variables that cloud this argument so I wanted to know if there is any systematic research about it.

Comment: You have a very simplistic view of cohort studies. Even if we could find a goal variable (= some way of measure "healthy"), which is already an exceedingly tough problem, we have tons of confounding variables which correlate with your two conditions, such as exposure to smog, access to different food, access to different levels of medical care, different stress levels, access to gyms, etc. So, if somebody ever made a study, found out that big city people are on average healthier than rural people, and concluded that it's due to more walking to work, this would be an example for bad science.

Comment: How can walking a few blocks and climbing a few stairs be "physically strenuous" for anyone other than extremely obese people, people who suffer from serious illness etc.?

Comment: Is this taking into account the high(er) levels of air pollution?

Comment: Your question now is basically "Why is walking healthy". Would you mind editing your question so that body and title are more descriptive of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all other variables are constant then yes.
In real life it depends.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3098122/

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for rather than people trying to prove they are smart by just dodging the core of the question. I guess the followup question is - do people in inner cities REALLY walk more than others.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat But then again, this answer does not give you anything but a personal opinion, additionally based on the assumption that there are no other factors. Basically you asked “Are people healthier when they move more?” and the reply was “Yes they are”.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat that would require research or may be a glimpse at the fitbit data

Comment: @Philipp its not a personal opinion. Setting aside existence of any medical condition people are healthier when they move.

Comment: -1 First of all, Welcome to Health.SE! This site works a bit different to most SE sites because we have the rigorous community policy that all answers must be backed up with sources. Would you mind to adhere to this and provide sources for your claim? The question was *Are big city residents healthier due to walking*, too which you replied if they walk more, they are healthier. This is partly wrong (sola dosis facit venenum) and is not an answer to the question. Maybe big city residents do something else differently than those who live in rural areas, which you haven't covered in your answer.

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma It also states that all the other variables are constant. Please read it again. And here you go https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3098122/

Comment: The question is inherently pointless as @Philipp stated.

Comment: @JayakrishnaPillai Thanks for the link. I do not need to see sources, as I'm partly aware of the scientific findings, but a good answer should incorporate references for their claims. You can [edit] your answer with references. This would be an outstanding answer if you'd take the time and list multiple advantages walking has to prove your point. I'd be happy to retract my vote and give you a +1 once the question is edited. Please ping me (using @username) once it is done so I won't forget.

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma Edit the question or answer?

Comment: @JayakrishnaPillai Expanding your answer with more information. I'll ask OP whether we can change the question as well.

Comment: It is not pointless. Use some common sense